# Why IList<childT> cant convert to IList<parentT>?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 classes:
`Parent` and `Child:Parent`.

When i do next:

```
IMyRepository<Child> _childRepository=new MyRepository<Child>();
IMyRepository<Parent> _repository=childRepository;
```

i get error  "Сan't convert source type to target type". 
Tell me please why this code is not working.

Comment: Because we want to prevent `_repository.Add(new SOmeOtherChildThatDerivesFromParentButIsnt_Child())` from compiling.

Comment: knittl's answer mentions covariance and contravariance - here's some great background reading on the subject - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, then you would be able to insert a `new AnotherDifferentChild()` – this can't possibly exist in a `IList<Child>`. If you want to learn more about the details, look up articles on *Covariance*, *Contravariance*, and *Invariance*.

If you want to create a new list, holding references of type `Parent`, you can use the `Cast<T>()` method from LINQ:

```
IList<Parent> parentList = childList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for bringing up C# 4.0's Covariance & Contravariance feature. I think the rest of your answer is irrelevant though.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: .NET 4 offers handling of cases involving co(ntra)variance, but they are a "problem" (so to say) in every OOP system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clued up on casting, but I don't think generics would do an implicit cast to the parent type.

but adding

```
childRepository.Cast<Parent>()
```

Should make it possible although you may have to make an extension for `IEnumerable<T>` that would create a new `IMyRepository<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<Parent> listOfParent = new List<Child>().Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

Or

```
List<Parent> listOfParent = new List<Child>().ConvertAll(x => (Parent)x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use slightly different class names, the reason you're not allowed to do this will become clear.

Consider this class hierarchy:

```
public class Mammal
{
}

public class Cat: Mammal
{
    public void Meow(){}
}
```

Now assume you have the following list:

```
IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>{ new Cat() }

cats[0].Meow(); // All is fine.
```

Now let's assume you can assign `cats` to an `IList<Mammal>`:

```
IList<Mammal> mammals = cats; // Not allowed, but pretend it is.

mammals.Add(new Mammal()); 

// Because 'mammals' is referencing 'cats', then adding an element to 'mammals'
// will affect 'cats' too - they are both the same list.
// So now cats has two elements; the first is a Cat and the second is a Mammal.

// So now what happens when we do this?

cats[1].Meow(); // Ask a Mammal to Meow(). Ooopsie!
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine what would happen if you could do such a thing. You could write code like the following:

```
    IList<Child> children = new List<Child>();
    IList<Parent> parents = children;
    parents.Add(new Parent());
```

Note that `parents` is still a reference to the same object as `children`, however we have managed to add an object that is not an instance of `Child` to a `IList<Child>`!

As another answer has mentioned, this is all to do with the issue of covariance (closely related to an area of mathematics known as [Category Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) - interesting if you get a chance to look at it).

Essentially, if we write `T-> S`, for two types where *`S` is polymorphic to `T`*, say `Parent -> Child`, then a generic is covariant if it preserves this relationship. For example `IEnumerable` is a covariant because `IEnumerable<Object> -> IEnumerable<String>`.  The compiler knows this, as you can cast an `IEnumerable<String>` to an `IEnumerable<Object>`.